# Hide "index.html" from Swagger URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, swagger-ui, .net-6.0, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I'm on .NET 6 (.NET Core WebAPI). Created a simple project from a template. VS created WeatherForecastController and configured Swagger.

Swagger runs on "api/docs/index.html"

When I hit "api/docs" it redirects to "api/docs/index.html". Is there a way to remove "/index.html" from the path? This is my Swagger config:

```
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(x =>
    {
        x.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "API");
        x.RoutePrefix = "api/docs";
    });
```

Comment: AFAIK, you need to use a reverse proxy to rewrite the URL completely

Comment: Yeah, I can go ahead and rewrite URL, but I thought this functionality would go with Swagger @>@

Answer (score 2):

Redirect to `index.html` is hard-coded in `SwaggerUIMiddleware` and you can't configure it.
Unless you replace the middleware with your own, there's no way to turn it off.

https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/67344fe0b7c7e78128159d8bf02ebfe91408c3da/src/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI/SwaggerUIMiddleware.cs#L62-L74

```cs
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
{
    var httpMethod = httpContext.Request.Method;
    var path = httpContext.Request.Path.Value;

    // If the RoutePrefix is requested (with or without trailing slash), redirect to index URL
    if (httpMethod == "GET" && Regex.IsMatch(path, $"^/?{Regex.Escape(_options.RoutePrefix)}/?$",  RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
    {
        // Use relative redirect to support proxy environments
        var relativeIndexUrl = string.IsNullOrEmpty(path) || path.EndsWith("/")
            ? "index.html"
            : $"{path.Split('/').Last()}/index.html";

        RespondWithRedirect(httpContext.Response, relativeIndexUrl);
        return;
    }

    if (httpMethod == "GET" && Regex.IsMatch(path, $"^/{Regex.Escape(_options.RoutePrefix)}/?index.html$",  RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
    {
        await RespondWithIndexHtml(httpContext.Response);
        return;
    }

    await _staticFileMiddleware.Invoke(httpContext);
}
```